# Convert Psych's AST to JSON

Tags: ruby, psych

I want to dump the AST produced by Psych to JSON. How can I do this?

```
gem 'psych'
require 'psych'
require 'json'

ast = Psych.parse_stream("me: 1");

p ast
```

`ast.to_json` doesn't give me the JSON tree.

Comment: http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/Psych.html, there is a `to_json` method thats working by creating a `Psych::Visitors::JSONTree` object. I guess you need to construct a `JSONTree` object somehow. Or maybe you can try if `to_json` is immediately available to you.

Answer (score -1):

You wouldn't want to directly convert an AST to JSON. You would first convert it to a Ruby object graph with `to_ruby`. You code works if changed like so:

```rb
gem 'psych'
require 'psych'
require 'json'

ast = Psych.parse_stream("me: 1");

p ast.to_ruby[0].to_json
```

Comment: This will return `{"me": "1"}`. I'm looking for the AST. not the parsed object